# Powershell Function App- Invoking Azure VM from Visual Studio installed in Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a function app written in PowerShell and when I am trying to run the function app from Visual Studio Code I am getting below **error:**
**OpenError: [VMName] Connecting to remote server VMName failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the
request because the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.**

I have Visual Studio Code installed in one of the VM from where I am trying to invoke a file in another VM using PowerShell.

I tried to restart WinRm, add certificates, add the VM as trusted resource, set proxy as 10.0.0.6:8080, did add http and https in inbound rule,etc.

Please let me know if I am missing out on any of the step.

Comment: Proxy is not always the right solution.  Proxy can cause errors and disabling proxies can solve connection issues.  If server name is not found be is to use Ping (does not need port number) to make sure you have a route.  If IP doesn't not work with Ping than try machine name.  IP only works if there is a mask that allows the route to complete.  Using name a route can get established without masks being setup.  Name ARPs a Server that has a list of Machine Names which can be used to establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @jdweng that,

> Using a proxy isn’t always the best option. Because proxies may generate errors, disabling them can resolve connectivity issues. If the server name cannot be determined, use Ping (which does not require a port number) to confirm that you have a route. If Ping fails using the IP, try using the machine name. IP can only operate if a mask is present that enables the route to be successfully completed. A route can be created using name without the need to set up masks. An ARP server is a server that maintains a list of machine names that can be used to establish the connection.

-- Try using the remote server’s IP address rather than its hostname.

-- Verify the accuracy and permissions of the credentials you are using to connect to the remote server and access the resources you are attempting to access.